# Invoke web service from URL

Tags: web-services, url, tomcat

I need to invoke the operation ***activaFolios*** from the following WSDL directly from the browser:

```
http://148.223.59.169:8080/activacionFolios/activacionFolios?wsdl
```

Can anyone tell me if this is posible? If it is possible, how should the URL be formed?